# Что можно использовать в качестве уникального целочисленного идентификатора ПК?

Tags: c++

Сотрудники работают в клиентах, написанных на C++. В каждый такой клиент зашит ID сотрудника. Клиенты передают на HTTP-сервер определённую информацию вместе со своим ID для разделения данных на сервере... В редких случаях 2 или более сотрудников могут использовать один клиент и, соответственно, работать под одним ID. Нужно чтобы на сервере данные с разных ПК с одним логином не перемешивались. Сейчас для решения этой задачи к ID дописывается GetTickCount() или какой-нибудь рандомно сгенерированный при старте пин-код, но надо, чтобы это значение не менялось, чтобы оно было фиксированным для каждого отдельного ПК и получалось программно при старте клиента. Также оно должно быть целочисленным.

**Что можно использовать в качестве такого значения (получать его нужно средствами C++)?**

*PS: IP-адреса клиентов могут повторяться, если они работают из одной сети, поэтому разделение по IP не подходит, а MAC слишком длинный для int-а. Всего в организации не более 1000 ПК*

Comment: Вначале вы пишете, что сотрудники могут работать на одном клиенте - т.е. на сервере один ID для разных сотрудников, но всегда разные для разных ПК - на них же разные клиенты стоят? А спрашиваете про *одинаковые ID с разных ПК* - в рамках вашего описания ситуация невозможная... А вообще кто мешает использовать логин вошедшего в систему?...

Comment: ID вшивается в клиент при скачивании установщика с сервера. Ничто не мешает сотруднику скопировать установщик на другой ПК и развернуть клиент с тем же ID и у себя, и на этом ПК. Но эти ПК сервер должен различать и запоминать

Comment: А чем вам GUID не устраивает? 128-битное число по сути.

Comment: А сохранить один раз в реестре или конфигурационном файле при запуске дописываемое значение религия не позволяет?

Comment: @VladD, размером. ToInt(string(int ID)+string(int UniqueID)) - полученное число должно поместиться в 4 байта, при длине string(int ID) от 3 до 4 символов.

Comment: @Iceman: А, ну да, GUID — это 16 байт.

Comment: @Harry, сохранить значение... мда, это я туплю, спасибо. Действительно можно при установке дописать в конец клиента сгенеренный установщиком рандомный пин, а клиент пусть себя читает и юзает это значение. Ну, чтобы без лишних файлов. ) Но вдруг рандом-генератор чисто случайно сделает два одинаковых значения для одного ID... шанс 1 к миллионам, но мало ли )

Comment: Тогда берите GUID, уж его-то гарантируют... :) А, прочел о ваших ограничениях... ну, берите CRC32 от GUID :) Шансы на совпадение мизерные. Как вариант - при первой установке клиент спрашивает у сервера - а такое уже было или нет?... Да что мы мучимся - `time(0)` и хватит - что, в одну и ту же секунду кто-то будет ставить на двух машинах? :)

Comment: На so есть древний вопрос на ту же тему: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474940/unique-computer-id. (правда, там нет ограничения целочисленности, но всегда можно взять crc или murmur). Кажется, что ничего лучше особо и не придумаешь. Ну разве что атомарно увеличивать счетчик где-то на сервере и раздавать его клиентам.

Answer (score 1):

Изначально постановка задачи кривая. Вы можете взять CRC32 от MAC-адреса. Но лучше запретить повторный логин с тем же ID то логаута предыдущего (или логаута по таймауту). Или принудительный логаут предыдущего при логине следующего